# Manipulating Strings to return concatenated username

Tags: python, string, concatenation

Whenever I try to display the Firstname with first initial attached to the end, I get an out of string index range error!

```
def ForeName():
    return raw_input("Please enter your Forename: ")

def MiddleName():
    return raw_input("please enter your middle name, if none leave blank: ")

def LastName():
    return raw_input("Please enter your last name: ")


def Test():
    ForeNameT = ForeName()
    MiddleNameT = MiddleName()
    LastNameT = LastName()
    if not MiddleNameT:
        first_username = ForeNameT[0:] + LastNameT[0]
    elif ForeNameT:
         first_username = ForeNameT[0:][0] #i want to display the first name with the initial of the first name attached to the end of the first name.
    else:
        first_username = ForeNameT[0:] + MiddleNameT[0]



    return first_username




print Test()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an argument to `Test` function by doing `def Test(name_method):` and then set `if` to `if name_method == 'without_middlename':`.

Try to figure out yourself what you would change `print Test()` to.

Comment: i have a rough idea that i need to call in the argument you just used to the print Test() line, just not sure how! As I said, not looking for the answer, just more concise informtaion pertaining to what im trying to do.

Comment: How do you pass an argument to a function? Try to find how to do that by googling.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you are trying to do, try changing your Test function:

```
def Test():
    ForeNameT = ForeName()
    MiddleNameT = MiddleName()
    LastNameT = LastName()
    if not MiddleNameT:
        first_username = ForeNameT + LastNameT
    else:
        first_username = ForeNameT + MiddleNameT + LastNameT

    return first_username
```

notice the changes to the variable names vs. the function names and the return value so print has something to actually print

Comment: raw_input returns a simple string so you don't need to use the [] which is the way to index into a list or to split a string, by saying [0:] you are asking for the 0 to end characters of a string, and [0] will give only the first character of the string,  I added the T to the names because without it you would be addressing the name of a function not a new variable name